# Could NOT find HDF5 during compilation (server)

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

I was able to compile perfectly a code using HDF5 in my computer but now I would like to compile it in a server.

In the server, HDF5 is well installed in the following path:

> /usr/local/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.17/lib/

But I got this error during the compilation using CMake:

> CMake Error at
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148
>   (message):   Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES
>   HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS   HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES) Call Stack (most recent call
>   first):
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindHDF5.cmake:690
>   (find_package_handle_standard_args)   CMakeLists.txt:4 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The beginning of my CMakeList.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 REQUIRED)

find_package (HDF5 NAMES hdf5 COMPONENTS C static) 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR}) message(STATUS ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR})
set (LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${HDF5_C_STATIC_LIBRARY})

include_directories(/usr/local/HDF_Group/)
link_directories(/usr/local/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.17/lib/)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
```

Could you please help me ?As I'm not well familiar with CMake, Maybe I did not link it properly...

Thank in advance,

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I solved my issue by doing this:

```
export HDF5_DIR=/usr/local/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.17/share/cmake
```

And I added it into my /home/user/.bashrc so that I don't have to do this command line each time.

Comment: It's unrelated to linking. CMake does not find the location of your HDF5. You might want to pass the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with the path to your HDF5 included.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I solved my issue. It was not because of CMake but because of the HDF5_DIR path. Look above.

Comment: Note that using HDF5_DIR is a kind of boutique solution, and setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is the more general, universally-applicable solution to this type of problem.